# How many Lambda triggers does a Dynamodb Stream (reasonably) allow?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

[AWS docs state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) that:

"You can subscribe up to two Lambda functions to the same DynamoDB stream."

and I've added more than two which seems to conflict with the documentation.

[image: Three Lambdas, One Stream]

What are the implications (if any) of having more than two Lambda Function Triggers assigned to the DDB stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation is to subscribe no more than two consumers, as having more than 2 can lead to throttling and ultimately increased latencies.

> For single-Region tables that are not global tables, you can design for up to two processes to read from the same DynamoDB Streams shard at the same time. Exceeding this limit can result in request throttling. For global tables, we recommend you limit the number of simultaneous readers to one to avoid request throttling.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-dynamodb-streams

Comment: Thanks @Leeroy, do you know the best way to have multiple shards for the same ddb stream that can be triggered by one or two lambda each?

Comment: I'm not sure on your definition of shard. But a given stream has many shards, and you can have up to 10 invocations of a lambda per shard, using parallelization factor. More than 2 consumers could cause throttling. If you need more you can use kinesis streams, or a fan out approach.